# What's the best way to write a wrapper for a C++ library, when rust-bindgen doesn't work on the original headers?

Tags: c++, rust, rust-bindgen

I'm trying to port a C++ library to Rust. One dependency isn't open-source, and I only have access to the header files. `rust-bindgen` doesn't generate valid bindings from these header files, and after searching online for a while, I came to the conclusion that I needed to write a wrapper for the aforementioned library. (This header files for this library are from https://github.com/wpilibsuite/ni-libraries, if it matters).

Because of these issues, I can't include the original header files in the wrapper's header files, but I can include the original headers in the actual cpp files.

To use classes, I've just forward-declared them, but some of these headers use typedefs and other fields inside the class as return types. There doesn't seem to be a (good) way to forward-declare or otherwise use these.

I'd like to know if my approach is correct, or if there's a better way to do this and I'm going the wrong way about this (it could be either in `C++` or with `rust-bindgen` itself).

An example of my current setup:

`closed-source.h`

```
class Foo {
    Foo* create();
    int getBar();
}
```

`wrapper.hpp`

```
class Foo;
Foo* foo_create();
int foo_getBar();
```

`wrapper.cpp`

```cpp
#include "closed-source.h"
#include "wrapper.hpp"

Foo* foo_create() {
    return Foo::create();
}
int foo_getBar(Foo* self) {
    return self->getBar();
}
```

Comment: Please tell me if you need more context

Comment: You're probably better off not using the actual types at all. Either declare your own `struct MyFoo` or settle for a bunch of `void`.

Comment: @o11c I need some functions to return a pointer to the object

Comment: The only thing you will be able to do with the returned pointer is to pass it back to some other function of the same library → return `void*` (or an alias) and have the other functions take a `void*`.

Comment: I updated the example in the post, issue is I’m actually *using* the pointer by passing it back to the wrapper (saw this approach online so I assume it works)

Comment: So? `int foo_getBar(void* self) { Foo* foo = self; return foo->getBar(); }`